# React Toolkit reducer Error, return new or modified state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

The sortBy method on my Slice throws the following error

```
An immer producer returned a new value *and* modified its draft. Either return a new value *or* modify the draft.
```

I believe I am returning a new state with characters modified.

```
export const charactersSlice = createSlice({
  name: "characters",
  initialState: INITIAL_STATE,
  reducers: {
    setCurrentCharacters: (state, { payload }) => {
      return {
        ...state,
        characters: payload,
      };
    },
    sortBy: (state) => {
      return {
        ...state,
        characters: state.characters.sort((a, b) => a.mass - b.mass),
      };
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: redux toolkit i guess

Answer (score 1):

`Array.sort` is returning itself. **Not a new** array. It will modify its orginal array.

Redux Toolkit detects that the original state is changed but you also returning a new state.

I believe you can just use this following snippet:

```
sortBy: (state) => {
    state.characters.sort((a, b) => a.mass - b.mass);
},
```

Redux Toolkit doesnt expect a return state, but I't will accept it if passed, The the docs:
https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createslice